# Quartz - recovery mechanism

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, recovery

I am new in quartz scheduler. I am interested in quartz recovery mechanism. Is there any documentation about this process? I tried to find but without success.

We have a problem when recovery mechanism is active. We have `SCHEDULERDETAIL` table that is connected with `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` table (`QRTZ_TRIGGERS` table is table that comes with quartz). They are connected with foreign key: in `SCHEDULERDETAIL` table it is `SCHEDULED_ID` column (defined as `NUMBER`) and in `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` is `TRIGGER_NAME` (defined as `VARCHAR`). When new task is created, new trigger is added to `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` table. `TRIGGER_NAME` from `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` descends to `SCHEDULERDETAIL` table.

When job is not executed (server is down, scheduler module is not active or some other reason), as far as I understood, recovery mechanism starts to work. In our case, recovery mechanism in `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` inserts record that contains `Strings` for `TRIGGER_NAME` and `TRIGGER_GROUP` properties - columns (`TRIGGER_NAME = recover_app2.1361843234382_1363216375567; TRIGGER_GROUP = RECOVERING_JOBS`). Because in other tables these properties are defined as number other tasks can not be executed, because of the connection between these two tables (mechanism tries to descend `TRIGGER_NAME` which is `String` to `SCHEDULED_ID` which is number), so error is generated. My question is, can I control these communication between quartz and database? If it is possible, how can I manage this? If i can not, how to avoid this situation?

I am using quartz-scheduler 1.8.

Comment: You would not need to look at these internal tables. Quartz provides how to handle missed trigger and refire trigger strategies. While scheduling your tasks/job you should use these APIs to correctly recover from missed trigger.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 
Can you give me some links where I can find how this trigger strategy looks like and how can I use API to apply this strategy in my own scenarion?
thanks in advance

Comment: for example look at trigger listener http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/TriggerListeners

Comment: Thanks for response.
I reproduced this situation and found the solution. Now I am interested in next scenario: how can I turn off recovery mechanism so recovery triggers will never run?